# Galois Theory and splitting field

Tags: galois-theory, splitting-field

So I was doing a past exam and am kind of stuck on this question, I know how to do part a and b but unsure on how to proceed with the remaining ones. Any help on those will be appreciated along with any hints. Thanks

[image]

EDIT

Here are my workings for the (a) and (b)

(a)

okay, for (a) we look at the roots for $x^7$ - 3, which are $\sqrt[7] {3}, \zeta_7 \sqrt[7]{3}, \zeta_7^2 \sqrt[7]{3}, \ldots , \zeta_7^6 \sqrt[7]{3}$ where $ \zeta_7 = e^((2i\pi)/7)$. now we claim that K = $Q(\zeta_7, \sqrt[7] {3})$, we show $Q(\zeta_7, \sqrt[7] {3}) \subset K$ and vice versa as $\sqrt[7] {3} \in K$ and $\zeta_7 = \zeta_7 (\sqrt[7] {3}/\sqrt[7] {3})$ and the other way is true because all of the roots are contained in $Q(\zeta_7, \sqrt[7] {3})$

As for the degrees, for $ \sqrt[7] {3}$ is 7 and for $\zeta_7$ is 6 and thus [K : Q] = 42

for (b), we know K/Q has finite elements hence it is Galois

Comment: So please show at least how you did part a and b, so that people don't downvote your question for lack of effort.

Comment: @Yeti Please edit your question post and put it there. That's where people expect to find it.

Comment: just did, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For (b), "has finite elements" isn't really what Galois means. For instance, $\Bbb Q(\sqrt[7]3)$ is *not* Galois. It is Galois because it is separable (this comes automatically in characteristic $0$) and normal (it is the splitting field of a polynomial, in this case of $x^7-3$).

For (c), the third Sylow theorem lets you conclude quite easily how many subgroups there are of order $7$: There is one. The corresponding intermediate field would be one which has order $6$ over $\Bbb Q$. If your answer to (a) was $\alpha = \sqrt[3]7$ and $\beta = e^{2\pi i/7}$, then it should be rather easy to guess what this field is.

For (d), you have the following two maps:
$$
\sigma: \alpha\mapsto \alpha\beta\quad \beta\mapsto\beta \\
\tau:\alpha\mapsto \alpha\quad\beta\mapsto \beta^3
$$
They are rather standard when it comes to the Galois group of $\Bbb Q(\sqrt[n]{k}, e^{2\pi i/n})$. The exponent $^3$ in $\tau$ must be chosen with some care so that $\tau$ doesn't get lower order than $n-1$ (for instance, $\beta\mapsto \beta^2$ has order $3$).

For (e), that's just straight-up calculation (note that $\tau^{-1}(\beta) = \beta^{5}$):
$$
\tau\sigma\tau^{-1}(\alpha) = \tau\sigma(\alpha) = \tau(\alpha\beta) = \alpha\beta^3= \sigma^3(\alpha)\\
\tau\sigma\tau^{-1}(\beta) = \tau\sigma(\beta^5) = \tau(\beta^5) = \beta
$$
where that last one also fits with $\sigma^3(\beta)$. So we have $\tau\sigma\tau^{-1} = \sigma^3$.

Finally, for (f), let $N = \langle \sigma\rangle$ and $H = \langle \tau\rangle$. Then our above result for (e) gives $G = N\rtimes_\varphi H$, with $\varphi:H\to\operatorname{Aut}(N)$ given by $\varphi(\tau) = \square\,^3$, the cubing automorphism.

Comment: I got everything else except (e), can you explain how you went from $\tau\sigma(\alpha)$ to $\tau(\alpha\beta^3)$?
and for the second equation, you've selected $\tau^{-1}(\beta)$ to be $\beta^5$?

Comment: @Yeti You're right, that's a typo. As for $\tau^{-1}(\beta)$, that follows from the fact that $(\beta^5)^3=(\beta^3)^5=\beta$, so $\beta\mapsto\beta^5$ is the inverse of $\beta\mapsto\beta^3$.